# How to comment out delay scheduling command in SLURM?

Tags: linux, slurm, sbatch

I used delay scheduling in SLURM and it has worked fine. Now I want to comment this out without deleting this; how can I do this?

```
#SBATCH --mem=50000                         # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)  
#SBATCH --begin=now+6hour                   # dealy scheduling
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00                      # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment or break the `#SBATCH` token any way you want while still leaving it as a valid Bash comment.

For instance:

```
#SBATCH --mem=50000                         # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)  
##SBATCH --begin=now+6hour                   # dealy scheduling
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00                      # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
```

or,

```
#SBATCH --mem=50000                         # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)  
# SBATCH --begin=now+6hour                   # dealy scheduling
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00                      # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
```

or even,

```
#SBATCH --mem=50000                         # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)  
# NO SBATCH --begin=now+6hour                   # dealy scheduling
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00                      # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
```